# What port does Skype for iPhone use?

Tags: iphone, applications, skype, network

I want to set up Skype to have priority on my router whem I'm skyping from my iPhone, but I can't figure out which port the app uses.

Any ideas?

Comment: I always thought skype used any open port because it just works anywhere everytime, behind proxies and firewalls unless it's blocked for specific traffic or per application on its own machine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's port 80 and port 443.  See this article on blocking of Skype 3G traffic

[www.bluecoat.com/doc/486](http://www.bluecoat.com/doc/486)

Answer (score 0):

[Skype and firewalls](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/support/user-guides/firewalls/technical/)

> Ideally, outgoing TCP connections to
>   all ports (1.65535) should be opened.
>   This option results in Skype working
>   most reliably. This is only necessary
>   for your Skype connection to be able
>   to connect to the Skype network and
>   will not make your network any less
>   secure.